# make dirvish follow softlinks during backup

Tags: debian

How can I make the dirvish to follow softlink directories?

My master.conf is:

```
bank:
    /work/dirvish
exclude:
    lost+found/
    core
    *~
    .nfs*
Runall:
    machine1-he

expire-default: +15 days
#expire-default: +6 month
```

And vault config:

```
client: machine1-he
expire-default: +1 months

rsync-option:
        --port
        873
<------>--sparse
tree: :backup

xdev: 0
index: gzip
log: gzip
image-default: %Y-%m-%d
```

Answer (score 1):

The dirvish uses rsync daemon during backups. The problem was the rsync daemon config:
use chroot = true

That made the rsync "don't follow symlinks"